# Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

Tags: android, gradle

I just rebuild my android project in android studio then got these errors.

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Nitesh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
       compileSdkVersion 21
       buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"
       defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'removed for security  concern'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
       }
        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.txt'

        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.25.10.jar')
compile files('libs/eventbus-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: first remove libraries which you are not using from gradle!!

Comment: have you upgraded your build tools version?

Comment: I removed all the libraries which we are not using in build.gradle but same error

Comment: Replace version numbers with the most recent ones as necessary.       buildToolsVersion "21.1.2" and clean your project at the end.                                                        http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html

Comment: set 21.1.2 but stil same problem